# Is there goto statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, goto

Is there a way to start at a specified line, like a goto statement?

Comment: obligatory xkcd comic: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Any particular reason you want to know?

Comment: I know you can in rspec. Might look at the source.

Answer (score 28):

First, it would be statement, not a command. Second, see [ruby-goto](https://rubygems.org/gems/goto). Third, note

> **Category:** Library/Evil

Comment: Wow, "Category: Library/Evil".

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke, but there actually Is a Category: Library/Evil. It currently includes ruby-goto as mentioned, as well as *segfault4r* : "Its a module that forces a segfault.

Answer (score 4):

There is the ruby command line switch `-x`.

```
 -x[directory]  Tells Ruby that the script is embedded in a message.
                Leading garbage will be discarded until the first that
                starts with “#!” and contains the string, “ruby”.  Any
                meaningful switches on that line will applied.  The end of
                script must be specified with either EOF, ^D (control-D),
                ^Z (control-Z), or reserved word __END__.  If the direc‐
                tory name is specified, Ruby will switch to that directory
                before executing script.
```

BTW, I'm pretty sure ruby-goto was, umm, a joke. I don't believe the download link has ever worked. Or am I just supposed to point people to it and keep quiet? I never know...

I liked Ryan's next line after announcing ruby-goto:

> Stay tuned for the next evil module...
>   ruby-malloc! Have a nice day.

Ryan is clearly a genius.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so (and, by all that's holy, it *shouldn't*).

But there's a [`goto`](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/list.rhtml?name=ruby-goto) module for it if you're feeling really masochistic.

Answer (score 2):

The goto lib is still with us :D https://rubygems.org/gems/goto/versions/0

Conserving the entire gem for posterity:

```
STACK = []

class Label
  attr_accessor :name;
  attr_accessor :block;

  def initialize(name, block);
    @name  = name
    @block = block
  end

  def ==(sym)
    @name == sym
  end
end

class Goto < Exception;
  attr_accessor :label
  def initialize(label); @label = label; end
end

def label(sym, &block)
  STACK.last << Label.new(sym, block)
end

def frame_start
  STACK << []
end

def frame_end
  frame = STACK.pop
  idx   = 0

  begin
    for i in (idx...frame.size)
      frame[i].block.call if frame[i].block
    end
  rescue Goto => g
    idx = frame.index(g.label)
    retry
  end
end

def goto(label)
  raise Goto.new(label)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at creating a gist that implements its functionality, [this is how it went](https://gist.github.com/Shannarra/a1def25cff80a14e5b26a9722a91469c).

Example of how my library works:

```rb
label_stack_main do
  x = 0

  label(:increment) do
    x += 1
    goto :example
  end

  label(:example) do
    puts x
    goto :increment if x < 10
  end
  
  label(:start) do
    goto :example
  end
end
```

And it's output:

```bash
$ ruby example.rb
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note that my library DOES NOT utilize exceptions in any way, shape or form.
Also, note that there's a reason the Ruby team didn't implement `goto` natively into the language, this thing I've made was just for fun :)